# Dimension of arrays in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran

In Fortan 77 arrays could be at most 7-dimensional. Is this restriction still there in Fortran 90? I can't find anything on this subject on [this](https://www.fortrantutorial.com/documents/IntroductionToFTN95.pdf) tutorial I have found on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also Fortran 90 is limited to a maximum rank of 7. Fortran 2008 increases this to a maximum rank of 15.

See also [The new features of Fortran 2008](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1408643.1408645), page 4:

> The maximum rank has been increased to 15. In the case of a coarray, the limit of 15 applies to the sum of the rank and corank.

Comment: The limit in Fortran 2008 is 15 minus the corank, rather than 15.  That is, an array may have a rank of 15, but not all arrays may have rank 15.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for pointing this out. I extended my answer.